# I could not find the lowest average

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to find the lowest student average in a golf game. but I could not find out how. all my attempts ended up finding the highest average which is the opposite of what I want to display.

*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*
*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    double total = 0; double totalr = 0;
    const int round = 3; double less=0;
    const int player = 5;
    string name[player]={"Mike Sims  ", "Paula Hill ", "Steve Jones", "Joll Burton", "Lee Smith  "};
    double average=0, avestudent, averound; string dummy;
    int score[round][player] =
    {  78, 71, 72, 73, 74 ,  76, 78, 75, 74, 79 ,  74, 75, 73, 72, 78  };    

    cout << "Player              Round1           Round2           Round3           Ave./Student"<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <player ; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(10) << left << name[i]; total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <round ; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(16) << right << score[j][i];
            total = total + score[j][i];    avestudent = total / (int)round;
        }

        cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
        cout <<setw(20)<< avestudent ;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Ave./Round ";
    for (int i = 0; i <round; i++)
    {
        totalr = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <player; j++)
            totalr = totalr + score[i][j];
        averound = totalr / player;
        cout << setw(13)<< "     "<<averound;
    }
    cout<< endl;
    double lowest = score[round][player];

    for (int j = 0; j < round; j++)
    {
        lowest = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < player; i++)
        {

            avestudent = total / (int)round;
            lowest = avestudent;
            if (score[j][i] < lowest)
                lowest = score[j][i];
        }
    }
    cout << lowest << " was the best recorded student average from the rounds of golf." << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(1) << endl;
}
```

Comment: ">> all my attempts "... what exactly were your attempts, besides posting the whole thing here?

Comment: Try switching the order of your scores and it will help you find out what you're doing wrong. For example, use this array of scores instead `{  78, 71, 72, 74, 73 ,  76, 78, 75, 79, 74 ,  74, 75, 73, 78, 72  }`

Comment: it means that i have tried my best to find an answer to that but I couldnt. i have looked all over youtube but I couldnt find something would help. Also, I am not waiting for someone to write me a code I want to know what is wrong with it. Thanks for seeing my post and I am sorry if I wasted your valuable time.

Comment: What are the results from using a debugger?

Comment: (amallard) thanks, but it is still giving me the highest average.

Comment: (Thomas Mattews) the student average should be 73.0 which is the lowest average but what is showing up is the highest average which is 77.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly I'm not exactly sure what your logic/ workflow is in trying to find the lowest average. In this case, I would just create an array to save the different averages. (So change your `avestudent` variable into an array)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double total = 0; 
    double totalr = 0;
    const int round = 3; 
    double less=0;
    const int player = 5;
    string name[player]={"Mike Sims  ", "Paula Hill ", "Steve Jones", "Joll Burton", "Lee Smith  "};
    double average=0, averound; string dummy;
    double avestudent[player];
    int score[round][player] = {  78, 71, 72, 73, 74 ,  76, 78, 75, 74, 79 ,  74, 75, 73, 72, 78  };

    cout << "Player              Round1           Round2           Round3           Ave./Student"<<endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <player ; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(10) << left << name[i]; 
        total = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <round ; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(16) << right << score[j][i];
            total = total + score[j][i];
            avestudent[i] = total / (int)round;
        }
        cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
        cout <<setw(20)<< avestudent[i] ;
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << left << "Ave./Round ";

    for (int i = 0; i <round; i++)
    {
        totalr = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <player; j++)
        {
            totalr = totalr + score[i][j];
        }
        averound = totalr / player;
        cout << setw(13)<< "     "<<averound;
    }
    cout<< endl;
    double lowest = score[round][player];

    for (int j = 0; j < round; j++)
    {
        lowest = avestudent[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < player; i++)
        {
            if (avestudent[i] < lowest) 
            {
                lowest = avestudent[i];
            }

        }
    }
    cout << lowest << " was the best recorded student average from the rounds of golf." << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
    cout << endl;
 }
```

Comment: I never thought of that, I just tried it and it worked thank you a lot, I appreciate that.

Comment: Glad to help. If you're happy with the answer, be sure to mark it as correct in case future StackOverflow'ers have a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
int sums[player] = {};
int lowest_score = 0;
int lowest_player = 0;
double lowest_avg = 0.0;
for (int r = 0; r < round; r++)
{
    for (int p = 0; p < player; p++)
    {
        sums[p] += score[r][p];
    }
}

for (int p = 0; p < player; p++)
{
    if ((p == 0) || (sums[p] < lowest_score))
    {
        lowest_player = p;
        lowest_score = sums[p];
    }
}
lowest_avg = ((double)lowest_score) / round;

std::cout << "The player with the lowest average score is " << name[lowest_player] << ".  With an average score of " << lowest_avg << std::endl;
```

Comment: we have not started using INT MAX yet. thanks for your help.

Comment: Seriously?  You're going to dismiss the answer just because you haven't been taught a concept?  You can definitely extrapolate an equivalent solution without using MAX_INT.  One idea would be to initialize `lowest_score` to `-1` instead and then use the expression `if ( (sums[p] < lowest_score) || (lowest_score == -1) )`. There's other similar ways to do the same thing without restructuring the answer.

Comment: There, I updated my answer for you.  You can show your appreciation for me doing your homework for you by at least upvoting the answer.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

The big issue with your code is that you're trying to initialize lowest to `score[round][player]`. You can't do this because these are the sizes of the array. 
If there is an array `int array[5];` you cannot access `array[5]`. The highest index that is reachable is `array[4]` because the array uses spaces 0,1,2,3,4 to hold the five integers.